# Испортится ли история гита после git push ветки с большим количеством смерженных коммитов?

Tags: git

Такая ситуевина: необходимо было подгрузить изменения из мастера в старую ветку, для этого сделал `git merge master`. Теперь висит сообщение:

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/branchName' by 123 commits.

Как правильно работать с гитом теперь? Если сделать push со всеми этими коммитами, то как они отобразятся в истории?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд всё просто. Сообщение говорит о том, что Ваша ветка на 123 коммита опережает ту, что у Вас на Гитхабе (или в другом глобальном хранилище) лежит. В этом нет ничего плохого. Просто Вы давненько не заливали изменения. Если сделать `git push` (я предполагаю, что в подробном изложении вопроса опечатка и ориентируюсь на заголовок), всё пройдёт успешно. Просто будет большой "скачок" по коммитам в глобальном хранилище, вот и всё.

Comment: Поддерживаю, так все и работает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Спасибо, а чего не проголосовали?

Comment: @V-Mor Просто интересно: а есть ли способ сделать merge не внося в историю целую кучу изменений? 
т.е чтобы шло примерно так: старые коммиты -> merge master -> новые коммиты

Comment: @raspberry367 Вы имеете в виду, чтобы новые изменения сразу появились в ветке без предыстории? Первое, что приходит в голову – скопировать файлы в стороннее расположение, перейти в нужную ветку, вставить файлы и сделать коммит. Получится, будто бы произошло одно большое изменение. Однако что-то мне подсказывает, что это не правильно. Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос на эту тему.

Comment: @V-Mor Большое спасибо!

Comment: @raspberry367 Рад помочь :)

Comment: да забыл ) теперь плюсанул

Comment: @V-Mor можно, на самом деле. git squash

Comment: @raspberry367 Обратите внимание на предыдущий комментарий, думаю, он будет Вам полезен (гуглится лучше как `git merge --squash`).

Comment: @KAGGDesign Да, то, что нужно!

Comment: @raspberry367, если планируете впоследствии делать «вливания» из master в эту ветку, то делать в ней «кашу» («squash») лучше не стоит.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin объясните пожалуйста, почему так делать не стоит

Comment: @raspberry367, на полях слишком мало места.